# How would I hook up this load cell to work with an HX711 amplifier?

Tags: load-cell

I’m trying to build a scale using this [load cell](https://www.mechanicsurplus.com/products/129764330?gclid=Cj0KCQjw_r3nBRDxARIsAJljleEmrYYoPCDx3JQvRAE4t8_rc3qSEJxccy31om5z1l0dl9oBY7nw1VQaAhaTEALw_wcB) which is different than the similar looking load cells in that it these are rated for 100kg, whereas the typical load cells are rated for 50kg.  More importantly, this load cell has four wires instead of three.  I have used four of the 50kg/3 wire cells with an HX711 amplifier by following this diagram:

[image: *enter image description here*]

My question is how can I hook four of these 100kg/four wire cells so I can weigh things up to 400kg?

Comment: Um, this sounds like a mechanical, not an electronic problem. If you need to weigh something heavier than these cells are rated for, you'll have to distribute the weight across all four. The rest is just a question of "did I read any short documentation of how a load cell works".

Comment: A *mechanical* issue?  Seriously?  Perhaps you ought to re-read the question again, because this has nothing to do with load distribution and everything to do  with the extra excitation wire.